# MongoDB field value to variable in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am taking entries from MongoDB and I want to do some modifications, data crunching etc and updating. In this particular example Iam trying for every document in collection
 `{u'time': 1405694995.310651, u'text': u'HOHO,r\u012bt ar evitu uz positivus ar vip bi\u013ceti kabat\u0101:)', u'_id': ObjectId('53cd621d51f4fbe9f6e04da4'), u'name': u'Madara  B\u013cas\u0101ne', u'screenName': u'miumiumadara'}` take its text value as a string, count its keyword values and after add to exact particular document field with keyword value.

I am struggling with taking text field as string so it can be operated. And also I havent found solution in python how to add new field to document with count variable. In a Mongo shell comands are easy, but here i dont know. Anything for me to look for?

```
db = conn.posit2014
collection = db.ceturtdiena

    cursor = db.all.find()
    for text_fromDB in cursor:

        print text_fromDB

        source_text = text_fromDB.translate(None, '#!@£$%^&*()_:""?><.,/\|+-')
        source_text = source_text.lower()

        source_words = source_text.split()

        count = 0  
        word_list = []
        with open('pozit.txt') as inputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                word_list.append(line.strip())

        for word in word_list:
            if word in source_words:
                count += 1

        #add count variable to each document
        # {$set : {value:'count'}}
```

Comment: I think it will help if you give a specific and simple example of a modification that you want to do (say by showing how you did it in the mongo shell) and then we can help you write that in Python.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK text_fromDB is just a dict so you can do this. (If you mean to update document)

```
text_fromDB['count'] = value
collection.update({'_id':text_fromDB['_id']}, {"$set": text_fromDB})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand everything you're ask. Let's go one piece at a time. To get the text field from your collection as a normal string try this:

```
collection = db.centurtdiena
for doc in collection.find():
    text = str(doc['text'])
    print(text)
```

Comment: Oddly didnt worked for me. I changed to this and now it works. `cursor = db.all.find()
for text_fromDB in cursor: text = str(text_fromDB['text'].encode('utf-8')) print(text)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    dinamic_precio  = 'precio0' + str(giro)    
    dinamic_fecha   = 'f0'      + str(giro)    
    
    clientM.FREE_FALLING_CANDIDATOS.update_one({'symbol': symbol}, {'$set': {dinamic_precio: price1, dinamic_fecha: datetime.now()}}, upsert=True)
```

That works for me. "giro" will modify the name of the field.

```
f01 2023-11-28T15:41:03.520+00:00  precio01 "0.10277000"
f02 2023-11-28T15:41:34.852+00:00  precio02 "0.10292000"
f03 2023-11-28T15:42:07.120+00:00  precio03 "0.10286000"
```